# Saving data in .txt file java

Tags: java

can someone help me with this? I want to save all data(like textfields , checkbox , radioButtton, scroll list) in .txt file when i press that btnSubmit .

```
btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(textField.getText().isEmpty()||(textField_1.getText().isEmpty())||(textField_2.getText().isEmpty())||(textArea_1.getText().isEmpty())||((radioButton_1.isSelected())&&(radioButton.isSelected()))||(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Select")))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Missing");
            else 

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Submitted");



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(your_file, append)); 
writer.write(your_string);
writer.close();
```

For btnSubmit:

```
btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(textField.getText().isEmpty()||(textField_1.getText().isEmpty())||(textField_2.getText().isEmpty())||(textArea_1.getText().isEmpty())||((radioButton_1.isSelected())&&(radioButton.isSelected()))||(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Select")))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Missing");
        else {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Submitted");
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new 
         FileWriter(new File("file.txt"), append)); 
         writer.write(textField.getText());
         writer.close();
        }
});
```

But Google search will give a better answer then mine.

Comment: This was very helpfully for me , thank you !